# Adding dynamic script src in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

How to use a dynamic path for the `src` attribute of a `script` tag in WordPress?

Would the below work?

```
<script id="css3-animate-it-js"
        src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/css3-animate-it.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Though above method would work, I think you should consider using the wordpress-implemented method: **enqueue script:**

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: I have use this code. But I can't use scrpt id:    wp_register_script('simpl-ui-isotope', SIMPLUI_ASSETS . '/js/jquery.isotope.min.js', array(), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('simpl-ui-isotope');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this would be:

```
// Hook into the enqueue action
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_prefix_enqueue_scripts');

function my_prefix_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_scripts('my-identifier', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/active-theme-sub-folder/script.js', array('jquery'));
}
```

Also check out the function here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: Thanks Yes I have got it.

Answer (score 0):

please use

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', plugins_url( '/custom5.js', __FILE__ ), false );
```

try as such to add your js file in plugin or theme

Comment: Thanks for help: I have use this code in my function.php    
 wp_enqueue_script('css3-animate-it-js', SIMPLUI_ASSETS . '/js/css3-animate-it.js', array(), false, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('css3-animate-it-js'); 
But I can't get this css3-animate-it-js id. 
Just I get source.
Please help

Comment: where is your js file can you please tell me r u customize your theme or plugin

Comment: I use it theme.

Comment: My footer.php code is:
<script id="css3-animate-it-js" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/css3-animate-it.js"></script>

Comment: then add theme_url and in single quote add your file name with current path

Comment: if you want to use like this then after add your script just check your file is included or not

Comment: Yes file is included but I can't get scrpt id

Comment: if file is added then check your code you are doing wrong code it's your code issue if you are not getting id...........

Comment: File is included but script not found. Now I wan't to get script id.